# I am trying to make a .app for my test first python script using playpus

Tags: python, platypus

This is my script

```
removed
```

it works fine through terminal but when i make it a .app with Platypus i get this when running the app

```
Hello How are you? 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/shameer/Desktop/Test Programs/questions.app/Contents/Resources/script", line 2, in <module>
    feeling = raw_input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Comment: Do you know you can put your questions in the raw_input calls? e.g. `feeling = raw_input("Hello. How are you?")`

Comment: Yes I know now but the day i wrote this it was my first day learning python and i am only 12 :p that doesn't fix it

Answer (score 1):

Platypus doesn't create an interactive terminal session, it just pipes your script output into a textfield. You won't be able to wrap interactive programs with it.